# Path, ArcSegment Computation from Center Point to Specific Point in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have ArcSegment defined in XAML and in code behind I need a computation to get Y value from center point of the arc to specific Y point. Please see image to understand better.

**XAML**

```
 <Canvas Name="canvas" Background="White" Opacity="99">
        <Path Stroke="Red" MouseLeftButtonDown="Path_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="250,250">
                            <ArcSegment Size="70,70" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise" Point="250,200"/>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
       
    </Canvas>
```

**C#**

```
//I got this from StackOverflow maybe someone can figure out for the correct computation.
     private void Path_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                var curve = sender as Path;
                var geometry = curve.Data as PathGeometry;
                var figure = geometry.Figures.FirstOrDefault();
                var arcSegment = figure.Segments.FirstOrDefault() as ArcSegment;
                var xStart = figure.StartPoint.X;
                var yStart = figure.StartPoint.Y;
                var startAngle = arcSegment.Point.X;
                var sweepAngle = arcSegment.Point.Y;
                var Rx = arcSegment.Size.Width; // this is radius width
                var Ry = arcSegment.Size.Height;  // this is radius height
                var centerX = xStart - Rx * Math.Cos(startAngle);
                var centerY = yStart - Ry * Math.Sin(startAngle);
                var endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle;
                var xEnd = centerX + Rx * Math.Cos(endAngle);
                var yEnd = centerY + Ry * Math.Sin(endAngle);
            }
```

**Screenshot**

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS2kg.png)

Comment: The y value of the center is the mean value of the y values of start and end point (since their x values are identical), i.e. 225. That minus 70 is 155, not 154.

Comment: Hi @Clemens, thank you so much! This solved my problem. It is indeed 155. I just relied on my mouse pointer. My formula is var meanY = (yStart+sweepAngle)/2-70;